# While loops for lists?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm pretty new to programming and I have a quick question. I am trying to make a Gaussian function for a range of stars. However i want the size of undercurve be at 100 for all the stars. I was thinking of doing a while loop saying that while the total length of undercurve be 100. However, I get an error and I'm guessing it has something to do with it being a list. I'm showing you guys my code to see if you can help me out here. Thanks!

I get a syntax error: can't assign to call function

```
import numpy
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import scipy
from scipy import stats
from math import sqrt
from numpy import zeros
from numpy import numarray


variance = input("Input variance of the star:")
mean = input("Input mean of the star:")

space=numpy.linspace(-4,1,1000)
sigma = sqrt(variance)

Max = max(mlab.normpdf(space,mean,sigma))
normalized = (mlab.normpdf(space,mean,sigma))/Max


def random_y_pt():
    return random.uniform(0,1)

def random_x_pt():
    return random.uniform(-4,1)

import random

def undercurve(size):
    result = []
    for i in range(0,size):
        y = random_y_pt()
        x = random_x_pt()
        if y < scipy.stats.norm(scale=variance,loc=mean).pdf(x):
            result.append((x))
    return result

size = 1

while len(undercurve(size)) < 100:
     undercurve(size) = undercurve(1)+undercurve(size)
     print undercurve(size)


plt.hist(undercurve(size),bins=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to show the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `undercurve(size) = undercurve(1)+undercurve(size)`? Assigning to a function call doesn't make sense.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: There is an error in your program:

Comment: @Robert: Try editing your question and pasting the error message there.  It'll be easier for people to find, and as you can see, you can't make multiline comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your error is something like `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call` then that's because of your line

```
undercurve(size) = undercurve(1)+undercurve(size)
```

Which is trying to set the output of the right-hand side as the value of `undercurve(size)`, which you cannot do.

It sounds like you actually want to see just the first `100` items in the list returned by `undercurve(size)`.  For that, use

```
undercurve(size)[:100]
```

Comment: This its where my novice with python comes in.  I required what you said and I got  type error: range () integer end argument expected, got list. Which makes sense since undercurve(size) would be a list. Doing a while loop was my idea. it doesn't matter how I do it as long as the end result would be right.

Comment: I know that will give me the actual values but I want to get exactly a 100 of them. Maybe its super obvious and I just can't see it. I mean that Len(undercurve(size))=100

Comment: @Robert which hundred?  The first hundred values are: `undercurve(size)[:100]`

Comment: Oh totally dif not remember I could just do that. Thank you!

Comment: @Robert some general advice would be to not call the undercurve function so many times, but rather, call it once with `uc = undercurve(size)` and refer to `uc` later, for example: `uc[:100]` will give the first 100 elements.